# Recent posts on a static home page

Tags: loop, homepage, customization

I want a static home page on my wordpress website, I have already set this up and have a bit of content on it, the next step is I want to have 5 recent posts underneath the content. As a normal page this is no problem, as soon as I set the page to a static home page, the posts disappear.

From hours of searching I am aware that I need 'multiple loops' in my template, I have found a few examples and tried to implement them in my template with no success. I think I pretty much have the code to bring the recent posts through, bust I think I'm having trouble markup and template tags to actually show the posts.

I hope this isn't too complicated to understand, and i really appreciate any help, I've been at this for 2 days with no progress at all. I can supply any code needed from templates or anything else.

My website - [www.completemuscleandfitness.com](http://www.completemuscleandfitness.com)

Ok, this is what i have so far

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
}
```

which shows this - www.completemuscleandfitness.com

How can i get it to look nice like the other post pages?

Comment: If you can supply the code why don't you do that?

Comment: I'm trying but it doesnt seem to be showing, ill use paste bin. This is what i have so far - http://pastebin.com/Qq08Z3Fp

Comment: I've already edited your question and it is waiting for peer review. See [Code Formatting](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Sorry, i probably sound really stupid! What's peer review?

Answer (score 1):

First, Welcome!

I guess you use the file `front-page.php` for displaying your homepage.
What you have to do, is add the following code into your `front-page.php`:

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

**More information about `wp_get_recent_posts()` can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts).**

Your template file will look something like the following:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="new_post">
        ...
    </div>                                  
</div>
```

You could try putting this code into `<div id="main">` right before the closing tag `</div>`:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="new_post">
        ...
    </div>
    <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
    <ul>
    <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
        }
    ?>
    </ul>                               
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As i have a static home page i use a template at the moment called page-home-2.php Can i put the code in there? The difficult part for me is knowing where to insert the code in the template?

Comment: You can add the code into `page-home-2.php`. I will edit my answer for you adding a short description where to place this code.

Comment: Mike could you possibly help me further?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom homepage template same as `index.php` in your active theme directory.

Inside that file you can create your own custom query and iterate through results.

Ex.

```
<h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array ( 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    $query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;
?>
</ul>
```

This you can think as a sample implementation. You can go further as needed.

Ex.

```
    <?php 

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;

/* Restore original Post Data 
 * NB: Because we are using new WP_Query we aren't stomping on the 
 * original $wp_query and it does not need to be reset.
*/
wp_reset_postdata();


/* The 2nd Query (without global var) */
$query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

// The 2nd Loop
while( $query2->have_posts() ):
    $query2->next_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title( $query2->post->ID ) . '</li>';
endwhile;

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

 ?>
```

You can get more information [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). And for multiple parameters of the query, refer [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters).

Comment: Thanks for you help, i have just inserted the first code in to my index.php to make a custom template. I now have recent posts showing but with no links and they a are just a small list above my content. How do i make the posts display like they do on other blog pages like this - http://completemuscleandfitness.com/index.php/training/

Comment: That is totally dependent on your current theme's DOM structure. That is, how the presentation logic is written through PHP and HTML. for instance, you can just copy paste the whole post display logic in your custom loop instead of the `echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';` statement and remove the wrapping `ul` to that.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Getting lots of input, really appreciate it. I kind of understand what what your saying. I think this is ultimately where i hit a brick wall. I've had the recent posts showing before but cant seem to get how they are displayed right. I just simply cant get my head around it. if i posted another theme blog template could anyone help from that?

Comment: I am unable to get what you are trying to tell. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: ok, i can get the recent posts to show on my static page, but they look a mess. There is probably some code i need to insert in to my custom page so that the posts show in the normal theme format. I just have no idea what code to put in a where, this code could probably come from another theme template? I'm asking that if i post a theme template can you help me place the code where it needs to be?

Comment: Surely! go ahead buddy.

Comment: Thanks! Firstly this is what i have so far in my custom template, this show posts but formatting - http://pastebin.com/Qq08Z3Fp The following is the blog template from my theme - http://pastebin.com/uJyfbEeg

Comment: I have modified the code and here is the link http://pastebin.com/ubhyxpJV. Just take a backup of your existing template file and paste this all code and I think you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Rohit, i have pasted the code into my custom template and activated it but the recent posts dont show on my home page?

Comment: I have made some edits. See this http://pastebin.com/QrcBXW0N. Try replacing this code with existing and try out.

Comment: Getting somewhere! Ok, now it shows the recent posts nearly looking how they should, but loops them so there are 3 posts continuously. Also my original page content has disappeared. Again, cant tell you how much i appreciate your help.

Comment: Go through various parameters of the query and I think you will be able to make it. You can refer the parameters [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters). Try changing the parameters so you can get the required no. of posts as per your criteria.

Comment: Ok thanks i'll give it a go. One last thing, any ideas on how i can get the other content showing again? The posts now take over all the content

Comment: Yeah sure. Just add this line `<?php get_template_part('home'); ?>` after `<?php
/*
  Template Name: Custom Homepage
 */
?>` and it should work probably. Try out and if it does not work, please point me to the code of your `home.php` file in the active theme directory. See if the file is present. If not try finding out which template is getting loaded for the line of code I have suggested.

Comment: ok it now shows but as a separate page quite strange - www.completemuscleandfitness.com Here is the template code - http://pastebin.com/3xDU9w3R and here is my home.php - http://pastebin.com/XELee582

Comment: Same as previous step, Backup the file and try replacing the code with [this](http://pastebin.com/Yf04AE8Q) and then try out.

Comment: same as before but footer meta stuff has disappeared. Sorry to be such a pain...

Comment: You are getting some problem in the DOM structure. I am able to see the footer part. Just check the proper DOM structure and I think that will resolve the problem.

Comment: I'm useless, i dont even know how to check the DOM structure...

Comment: Were you able to workout something? Have you modified the page as desired? Feel free if any help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, I think you are all working much too hard.

Seems to me that the "recent posts" widget should be all you need.

Example:

http://wordpresstest.hjcs.org

The "Recent News" is the "recent posts" widget.

(This site is still under construction--that's why I have "test" in the sub-domain.)